# bind multiple events with jQuery: "change" and "document ready"

Tags: jquery

How do I get `$('#Cate1')` value on both `document ready` and `change` events?

HTML:

```
<select name="cate1" id="Cate1">
<option value="0">Main Category</option>
<option value="1">s1</option>
<option value="2">s2</option>
```

jQuery:

```
$( "#Cate1" ).on( "change", function() {
    console.log($( "#Cate1" ).val());   
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By triggering the event on pageload

```
$(function() {
    $("#Cate1").on( "change", function() {
        console.log($( "#Cate1" ).val());
    }).trigger('change');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply do like this,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log($( "#Cate1" ).val());
    $( "#Cate1" ).on( "change", function() {
     console.log($( "#Cate1" ).val());
    })
});
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/8N6fP/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    var cate1 = $('#Cate1');
    cate1.on( 'change', function() {
        console.log($(this).val());
    });
    cate1.trigger('change');
});
```